# Multiple loop for range? For a certain range?

Tags: swift, xcode

While count is between 1...50 do something

for 50...100 do something else

Tried searching stack overflow, but it doesn't look like I'm looking for the right terminology.

I'm currently using the code below, but it seems a bit wordy to me? Is there a better alternative?

```
for _ in 0...50 {
    cell.collectionImage.image = PhotoArray[indexPath.row]
}
for _ in 50...100 {
    cell.collectionImage.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
}
```

Comment: @matt Right now, it's a collection view that's has 6 photos. When the user only uploads 1-6 of his/her own photos(varies), I need all the other images to be a grey photos. If not, it needs to populate theirs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty common way to perform loops.

Note that if you are trying to loop from 1 to 50, and 51 to 100, you should loop from 1 to 50 and 51 to 100, not 0 to 50 and 50 to 100.

```
for _ in 1...50 {
    cell.collectionImage.image = PhotoArray[indexPath.row] // This part of your code does not make sense.
}
for _ in 51...100 {
    cell.collectionImage.image = UIImage(named: "logo") // This part of your code does not make sense.
```

Note too that the body of each of your loops replaces `cell.collectionImage.image` with different values, over and over. That part doesn't make much sense.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. It is assigning the same Image to the same cell 50x instead of once

Comment: @LeoDabus, That is the OPs code. I don't know what they intended, so I couldn't correct it. (I pointed out that it doesn't make sense as the last part of my answer.)